# Generate json schema with play-json

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm using [json writes](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson) to transform simple case classes to json. Somethink like:

```
case class JobStarted(jobId: Long, jobStatus: String)
...
implicit def jobStartedWrites = Json.writes[JobStarted]
```

This transforms an instance of `JobStarted` to json like:

```
{
  jobId: 1,
  jobStatus: "running"
}
```

But i want to be able to generate the plain schema for the class:

```
{
  jobId: Number,
  jobStatus: String
}
```

Is there any way to do this using json writes ([json inception](http://mandubian.com/2012/11/11/JSON-inception/))? I am using Scala.

Comment: Consider using scala reflection to get the parameters+types of JobStarted.apply(), and just map them into JSON.  A "Writes" only makes sense to use in this context, I think, if you create some meta-types that you are mapping, e.g., a Writes for "MyJsonClass" and maybe! one for "MyJsonField".  MyJsonClass would be a wrapper for the reflection data.